# 2001 Ford Ranger 4.0 water leak

Tags: leak, ranger, water

have water leaking inside on passenger floorboard when it rains.  I think it may be a plugged cowl drain on that side, because if I park that side at night on something to raise it the water will drain towards drivers side and not enter the cab.  Not sure how to access to clear cowl drain?

Comment: Is there a sunroof / moonroof? And have you checked for a clogged or detached drain tube that runs down the A pillar to the area you mentioned?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: thank you for responding.  No sun/moon roof.  I did  look for a drain tube, couldn’t locate one?  I noticed on older rangers theres a panel cover on the engine bay you can remove and access the cowl area to clear out built up debris.  I have what looks like a small access cover on the drivers side, but nothing on the passenger side.  Also cant really access that area from within the door/fender area when the passenger door is open?  Unless you or anyone has a better idea, I think I will just run a garden hose on the windshield and cowl area n see if I can locate where it’s coming in from.